# Why is underscore not a valid name in new Python match?

Tags: python, python-3.10, structural-pattern-matching

`_` score can be used as a variable name anywhere in Python, such as:

```
_ = 10
print(_)
```

However, it is not accepted here:

```
d = dict(john = 10, owen=12, jenny=13)
match d:
    case {'john' : 10, 'jenny': _}:
        print('does not work', _)
```

```
ERROR: print('does not work', _)
NameError: name '_' is not defined
```

Yet, perfectly fine to use as follows:

```
d = dict(john = 10, owen=12, jenny=13)
match d:
    case {'john' : 10, 'jenny': a}:
        print('does not work', a)
```

Why is `_` not a valid variable name in new match in Python 3.10?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a match statement, `_` is a [wildcard pattern](https://peps.python.org/pep-0622/#wildcard-pattern). It matches anything without binding any names, so you can use it multiple times in the same `case` without having to come up with a bunch of different names for multiple values you don't care about.